# Angular FormGroup cannot assign to read only property 'status' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular-forms, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx with Angular 12. Below is the redux implementation

```
export interface AdminProductState {
  productDetailformValidStatus: FormGroup;
  productDetails: ProductDetailsCommand;
}

export const initialState: AdminProductState = {
  productDetailformValidStatus: new FormGroup({}),
  productDetails: {} as ProductDetailsCommand
};

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(Product_Form_Validation, (state, action) => (
    {
      ...state,
      productDetailformValidStatus: action.productDetailformValidStatus,
      productDetails: action.productDetails
    }
  )),
);

export function AdminProductReducer(state: AdminProductState | undefined, action: Action): any {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

`productDetailformValidStatus: FormGroup;` is defined as `FormGroup` and it has been initialized as `new FormGroup({})`,

From the dispatched method I am passing the new FormGroup as below

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.createControls();
    this.adminProductState.productDetailformValidStatus = this.form;
    this.productDetailsCommand.categoryId = 'asdasd2323';
    this.productDetailsCommand.title = 'hello titile';
    this.productDetailsCommand.description = 'thisisthedescription';
    this.productDetailsCommand.subCategoryId = 'thisisthetesting';
    this.adminProductState.productDetails = this.productDetailsCommand;
    this.store.dispatch(Product_Form_Validation(this.adminProductState));
  }

 protected createControls() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.controlsConfig.container.layoutConfig.forEach((layout, index) => {
      layout.componentConfig.forEach(controls => {
        this.bindControl(controls, group, index)
      })
    });
    return group;
  }
```

Now the `this.form` contain new controls and form status is invalid, while doing this I am facing issues as below

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'status' of object '[object Object]'
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_rawValidators' of object '[object Object]'
```

These errors are all from core.js. What's wrong I am doing I am not able to find it out.

[image]

From the redux tool

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to replicate this on StackBlitz?

Comment: @SiddAjmera here is the stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-opjjrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. You can check in the console output the errors

Comment: @SiddAjmera you can ignore the error  No component factory found for TextboxComponent that is a different error not related to the FormGroup.

Comment: Can't seem to find any documentation for the `@falcon-ng/core` that you're using. That package seems to be causing this error. Maybe it's not compatible with the version of Angular that you're using. Or do you have a link to their documentatino?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I have added a new repo with proper version https://github.com/anandjaisy/reduxWithFormBuilder and @falcon-ng/core is developed by me samples can be found here https://anandjaisy.github.io/Angular-Dynamic-Form-Builder/ and code can be found here https://github.com/anandjaisy/Angular-Dynamic-Form-Builder

Comment: If you are looking for the create control code can be found here https://github.com/anandjaisy/Angular-Dynamic-Form-Builder/blob/feature/base_form/projects/falcon-core/src/lib/common/base-form-component.ts

Comment: @SiddAjmera If I use the delay it works for me. Something like this setTimeout(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(Product_Form_Validation(this.adminProductState));
    }, 1000);. But not sure why not without delay

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this to solve the issue

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createControlAsyncTask()
      .then(() => this.store.dispatch(Product_Form_Validation(this.adminProductState)));
  }

  createControlAsyncTask() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.form = this.createControls();
      this.adminProductState.productDetailformValidStatus = this.form;
      resolve('done');
    });
  }
```